# Handling multiple external sources in Flask-Socketio

Tags: python-3.x, redis, flask-socketio

I am pretty new to Flask. I am writing a small application in Flask-socketio. I have 3 different feeds of json. I have installed redis using pip and the server using apt. The service is running. Now, for the problem. Each of say 3 users can have a choice of his feed. Example: user 1 can have feed1 and feed2, user2 has feed3 and user3 has feed1. I don't know how to route these users to the required rooms. I am able to get response of one source as below. I have come till here. Any help would be appreciated.

Server.py:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_socketio import send, emit
from flask_socketio import join_room, leave_room

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://')

@socketio.on("connect")
def connect():
    print("Connected")
    emit('status', {'status': 'Connected'})

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

@socketio.on_error()
def error_handler(e):
    print("Error")

@socketio.on("join")
def on_join(data):
    room = data['room']
    print("Joined room", room)
    join_room(room)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

The client:

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.on("status")
def status(data):
    print(data['status'])

@sio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print("I'm connected!")

@sio.event  
def connect_error():
    print("The connection failed!")

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print("I'm disconnected!")

@sio.on("json_response")
def getJSON(data):
    print(data)

sio.connect('http://localhost:5000')
sio.emit("join", {'room': 'chat1'})
```

External Sources:
one.py:

```
socketio = SocketIO(message_queue='redis://')
##  get the data from DB and convert to json
socketio.emit("json_response", {'payload': jsonStr})
```

two.py & three with same usage:

```
socketio = SocketIO(message_queue='redis://')
##  get the data from DB and convert to json
socketio.emit("json_response2", {'payload': jsonStr})
```

three.py has the above syntax as well.

Comment: Each client is joining a room for their chosen feed(s), correct? Then in one.py, two.py and three.py you have to add the `room` argument to your emits, so that only those subscribed to the correct room get those events.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse @Miguel. It works when I specify one room per user. How do I make it 2 or more rooms per user. Tried using a list, dict but returns unhashable. So tried a tuple, but the json is not received by the client. Also should I use only one message like below for all the clients. Thanks.
@sio.on("json_response")

Comment: Call `join_room` once per room. A user can join unlimited number of rooms.